# Updating set of data in the database in QT C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sql-update

I want to update my fiction table. I have to classes.

fictioninner.cpp

```
bool FictionInner :: updateMaterials(int fic_id,int copies, int shelf,int edition)
{
    QSqlQuery query ;

    query.prepare("update fiction set no_of_cpy =:copy,shelf_no=:shelf,edition=:edition"
                  " where fic_bk_id=:id");

    query.bindValue(":copy",copies);
    query.bindValue(":shelf",shelf);
    query.bindValue(":edition",edition);
    query.bindValue(":id",fic_id);
    return flag = query.exec();
}
```

fictionsection.cpp

```
void FictionSection::on_btnEdit_clicked()
{

    QString noOfCpy = ui->lneditMngCpy->text();
    int copy;
     if(!noOfCpy.isNull())
     {
          copy = noOfCpy.toInt();
     }
       int shelf = ui->spinbxMngShlf->value();

       int edition= ui->spinbxMngEdtn->value();

       QString ficId = ui->lneditMngFicId->text();
           int fictionId;
           if(!ficId.isNull())
           {
               fictionId = ficId.toInt();
           }

        FictionInner fiction;

  // assigning bool value to flag variable after running the query
        flag = fiction.updateMaterials(fictionId,copy,shelf,edition);
        if(flag == true)
     {
     QMessageBox :: information(this,"Successfull","Values updated successfully",QMessageBox::Ok);
     }
 else
 {
     QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error","Couldn't update the values");
 }


}
```

Data is not edited in the table. flag boolean returns false. All the data are stored in the database in INT format. I can't figure out my problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#lastError <= use this to get information.

Comment: I checked the values of each variable using qDebug()<<. All print int values. so there aren't empty.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You can't debug your issue without knowing the exact error that call to exec is triggering.

Comment: There is no error. Messagebox says that record is not updated.

Comment: See my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Before updating your record, You should open your database then construct QSqlquery object using open database object.

Comment: I have connected to the database at the beginning of the project. I checked if im connected to the database using if(dbconopen()){ }. It showed that Im connected.

Comment: do something like : QSqlQuery query(database) ;